# Mysql Triggers: Track changes

Tags: mysql, triggers, history

I don't know if this is possible, but I want to track changes of the table 1.

In the database the following two tables exists:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`table1` (
  `idtable1` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `B` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `C` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtable1`))
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`table2history` (
  `idtable2history` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `columnName` ENUM('A', 'B', 'C') NULL,
  `columnPrimaryKey` INT NULL,
  `columnNewValue` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `changetimestamp` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtable2history`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**If the following instructions is executed:**

```
UPDATE table1 SET A="ABC", B="XYZ" WHERE  idtable1=50;
```

**The Trigger "BEFORE UPDATE" should execute:**

```
INSERT INTO table2history (idtable2history, columnName, columnPrimaryKey, columnNewValue, changetimestamp)
VALUES (NULL, "A", "50", "ABC", NOW());

INSERT INTO table2history (idtable2history, columnName, columnPrimaryKey, columnNewValue, changetimestamp)
VALUES (NULL, "B", "50", "XYZ", NOW());
```

**If the following instructions is executed:**

```
UPDATE table1 SET A="123", B="456", C="789" WHERE  idtable1=20;
```

**The Trigger "BEFORE UPDATE" should execute:**

```
INSERT INTO table2history (idtable2history, columnName, columnPrimaryKey, columnNewValue, changetimestamp)
VALUES (NULL, "A", "20", "123", NOW());

INSERT INTO table2history (idtable2history, columnName, columnPrimaryKey, columnNewValue, changetimestamp)
VALUES (NULL, "B", "20", "456", NOW());

INSERT INTO table2history (idtable2history, columnName, columnPrimaryKey, columnNewValue, changetimestamp)
VALUES (NULL, "C", "20", "789", NOW());
```

**Do you know an intelligent solution for this problem?**

Comment: Yes, it is possible to achieve thus. What have you tried so far?

Comment: create a copy of the table with 3 fields more. a timestamp, a type where you store insert, delete or update, and field for username. The create 3 tiggers on INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE where put the hole row into the new table and add timestamp, type and user. so you can rollback to each time and see what change

Comment: I thank you for the answers.

@bernd-buffen Thank you for a possible solution. But I'd to implement it exactly as described above.

Comment: @Shadow Can you please give me a hint? I do not know how to deal with the different UPDATE commands. In the event that a one or more columns to be changed.
    CREATE TRIGGER `db`.`before_update_table1`
        BEFORE UPDATE ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            INSERT ...
        END
... I do not know how to deal with it, if only one column A is updated or if column A and B are updated. For this, I am looking for an intelligent solution. I do not need a complete solution from you, but a hint or instructions would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each column you want to track in the trigger body, checking for null-safe inequality:

```
IF NOT (NEW.A <=> OLD.A) THEN
  INSERT INTO table2history (idtable2history, columnName, columnPrimaryKey, columnNewValue, changetimestamp)
  VALUES (NULL, "A",NEW.idtable1, NEW.A, NOW());
END IF;

IF NOT (NEW.B <=> OLD.B) THEN
...
```

The `IF NOT (expr1 <=> expr2)` test uses the null-safe equality comparison ("spaceship") operator `<=>` which, unlike a proper equality comparison, will consider `NULL` values equal, and comparisons of non-null values against `NULL` on either side to be `FALSE` instead of `NULL`, and the leading `NOT` inverts the test... so if the old value is not the same as the new value for the row, the `INSERT` query is run, otherwise nothing happens since the value didn't change.

`OLD` and `NEW` are special aliases for the old and new versions of the row.  They are equally valid and contain the same values for `BEFORE UPDATE` and `AFTER UPDATE`, but a trigger that actually *modifies* the `NEW` image only works in the `BEFORE` trigger.  `BEFORE`, `NEW` means "what the row *will be* updated to," and `AFTER`, `NEW` means "what the row *has been* updated to."

You probably will actually want to write this trigger as `AFTER UPDATE`, simply because you might later want to add a different `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that does validation of the proposed update, since only one trigger for each timing can be defined (before MySQL 5.7), and that would allow this trigger to be left alone.

The trigger has to iterate through each column you're tracking using static queries, one for each column, since triggers do not support using prepared statements and dynamic SQL. Writing (generating) the trigger body by iterating through the columns with a script will save you some typing time, but for now you could write it out by hand and the above example should do exactly what you intend.

Your trigger body will look like it's doing a lot of work, but the server will run through all of these very quickly.